# How do I simply convert string?

Tags: javascript

How do I convert a string `var a = "123456";` in to an array `z = [1,2,3,4,5,6];`? I tried everything and nothing seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using split('') with Number works using JavaScript-C:

```
'123456789'.split('').map(Number)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var z = "123456".split();
```

See javascript docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and for casting to number the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var array = '123456'.split('').map(Number);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```